# Sending email from SSRS repor 2008

Tags: email, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, send

I have the below supplier data in SSRS 2008 report.

```
ID    Name    Details    Email
1     abc      d1       rob.b@gmail.com
2     def      d2       pat@gmail.com
3     ghi      d3       golf@gmail.com
4     dft      d4       rob.b@gmail.com
```

I need to send the relevant details to each email id. For example, in the data above, I need to send the entire record of ID 1 and 4 to rob.b@gmail.com.
Is there any way to send just the relevant details to the emails given in the report. Could someone please advise.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** - you can use a **Data Driven Subscription** to do this in SSRS - if you have the Enterprise version of SQL Server.

If you do not have the Enterprise version, you can still do this with a little bit more effort using a scheduled Stored Procedure to emulate the data driven subscription.

Either way, you would have a report that works with a parameter to identify a single record. Then the separate data driven part would have a different query that gets a list of IDs that you need for the report along with the e-mail address to send it to. The data driven part will then generate a separate report for each of the ID parameter that you created in the report and then send them to the address.

Data Driven Subscription properties:
[image: Data Driven Subscription]

Unfortunately, both methods are too big of a topic to be covered in an answer.

[MSDN - Data Driven Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-data-driven-subscription-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017)

[MSSQLTips.com - simulate-reporting-services-data-driven-subscriptions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4249/simulate-reporting-services-data-driven-subscriptions-on-unsupported-editions/)

Here's a SP that I made to generate multiple e-mail:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RECORD_REVIEW_GENERATION]

AS
DECLARE @SUBSCRIPTION_ID AS VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT SETTING_VALUE FROM WORKING_STORAGE.dbo.SETTINGS WHERE SETTING_NAME = 'REVIEW_SUBSCRIPTION')
DECLARE @SUBJECT VARCHAR(200) 
DECLARE @COMMENT VARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @REVIEW_ID VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @EXTENSION_SETTINGS XML
DECLARE @PARAMETERS XML
DECLARE @RECORD_ID AS INT 
DECLARE @MAX_RECORD_ID AS INT 
DECLARE @END_DATE AS DATE = GETDATE() - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())    --PREVIOUS SUNDAY
DECLARE @START_DATE AS DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -6, @END_DATE)   --PREVIOUS MONDAY
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(500) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @END_DATE, 112)



SELECT @EXTENSION_SETTINGS = ExtensionSettings, @PARAMETERS = [Parameters]
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
WHERE SubscriptionID = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID;



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#REVIEWS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #REVIEWS 

CREATE TABLE #REVIEWS(ReviewID VARCHAR(50), ProviderName VARCHAR(250), SiteIDNo VARCHAR(20), 
                        ReviewDate VARCHAR(12), UserName VARCHAR(250), VisitPurpose VARCHAR(250), 
                        NoOfPhysicians INT, NoOfRecords INT, RECORD_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                    )
INSERT INTO #REVIEWS(ReviewID, ProviderName, SiteIDNo, ReviewDate, UserName, VisitPurpose, NoOfPhysicians, NoOfRecords)
SELECT ReviewID, ProviderName, SiteIDNo, ReviewDate, UserFirstName + ' ' + UserLastName AS UserName, VisitPurpose, NoOfPhysicians, NoOfRecords 
FROM KHSSQLODSPRD.QI_SITE_REVIEW.dbo.RecordHeader 
WHERE ExportDate BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE
ORDER BY ReviewDate


SET @RECORD_ID = 1
SET @MAX_RECORD_ID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RECORD_ID), 0) FROM #REVIEWS)


    WHILE @RECORD_ID <= @MAX_RECORD_ID 
    BEGIN

        SELECT @REVIEW_ID = ReviewID, 
                @SUBJECT = 'Review - ' + ProviderName, 
                @COMMENT = CAST(@RECORD_ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' of ' + CAST(@MAX_RECORD_ID AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                            + ' Review Surveys for the week ending ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @END_DATE, 110)) + '.' 
                            + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ProviderName + ' [' + SiteIDNo + '] - Reviewed ' + RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ReviewDate, 110)) 
                            + '. Review ID ' + ReviewID  
                            + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + VisitPurpose + ' visit for ' + CAST(CAST(NoOfPhysicians AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' physicians with ' 
                            +  CAST(CAST(NoOfRecords AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' records by ' + UserName + '.'
        FROM #REVIEWS 
        WHERE RECORD_ID = @RECORD_ID


        SET @REVIEW_ID = LOWER(@REVIEW_ID)  

        --SET EXTENSION OPTIONS
        SET @EXTENSION_SETTINGS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="Subject"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@SUBJECT")');
        SET @EXTENSION_SETTINGS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="Comment"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@COMMENT")');

        --SET REPORT PARAMETERS
        SET @PARAMETERS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="SITE_ID"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@REVIEW_ID")');


        --UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION PARAMETERS 
        UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions
        SET ExtensionSettings = CAST(@EXTENSION_SETTINGS AS VARCHAR(8000)), 
            [Parameters]      = CAST(@PARAMETERS AS VARCHAR(8000))
        WHERE SubscriptionID = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID


        EXEC dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID;


        --WAIT WHILE REPORT GENERATES 
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03.000';

        --IF REPORT IS STILL EXECUTING, WAIT SOME MORE
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 'X' FROM dbo.Event WHERE EventData = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID ) OR EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 'X' FROM dbo.Notifications WHERE SubscriptionID = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
                        BEGIN
                            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.000';
                            PRINT 'Waiting for subscription to finish'
                        END


        SET @RECORD_ID = @RECORD_ID + 1

    END  --END OF LOOP 

--      SET @FLAG = 1
```

You'd add the TO address the same way as the **Comment** is updated. The @Review_ID is passed to the report as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hannover Fist for your response. I am using 2008 standard edition. I don't see the same things in properties as shown above. I tried giving the query in step3 that has email ids in parameter, but it is giving error the operation you are attempting on item is not allowed for its type. Sorry, I am using this feature for the first time.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Can you please help. Thanks.

Comment: The Standard Edition won't have the Data Driven Subscription option so you won't have the ability to set them using a query. The one I showed was 2016 so it would be different from your 2008 Report Manager. Are you trying to assign the TO value to use your e-mail address? `SET @EXTENSION_SETTINGS.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="TO"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@emailaddress")');`

Comment: Where should I give the above code? and will it work in SSRS 2008 standard edition if I give the above code? Sorry for asking questions as I am a novice and haven't used this feature.before..Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry, just realised that I am using enterprise edition. Can you please tell me where do I use the above code in enterprise edition> Thanks